# XSLT if statement on element with multiple attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML code:

```
<MainElement name = "apple">
   <Parameter variable1 = "foo" variable2 = "bar"/>
   <Parameter variable1 = "foo" variable2 = "notBar"/>
```

I am using xsl to print out the name of the `MainElement` if it contains a parameter with both `variable1 == "foo"` and `variable2 == "bar"`, as follows:

```
<xsl:for-each select = "MainElement">
   <xsl:if test = "Parameter/@variable1 = 'foo' and Parameter/@variable2 = 'bar'">
      ...
   </xsl:if>
   <xsl:if test = "Parameter/@variable1 = 'foo' and Parameter/@variable2 = 'notBar'">
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that this xsl code doesn't examine if one `Parameter` element contains both appropriate attributes, it looks at both Parameter elements to see if either contains the appropriate attributes.

I know I could try another method without the `if`'s, but now for my own curiosity I want to know how can I have the if statement look for the attribute conditionals in one specific element, not among both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the tests within a single predicate test on `Parameter`.

For example, change

```
Parameter/@variable1 = 'foo' and Parameter/@variable2 = 'bar'
```

to

```
Parameter[@variable1 = 'foo' and @variable2 = 'bar']
```

so that the test concerns a *single* `Parameter` child of `MainElement` that has both targeted attribute values, rather than possibly separate `Parameter` elements that could separately qualify.

Comment: kj you've helped me twice the past two days.  Thanks for sharing the wisdom.